# How to carry forward the bash aliases to remote machines?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I use a lot of aliases in my linux box. when I ssh into a remote machine, it would be very convenient to have those aliases present. I am looking at set of commands which would help me carry forward the aliases to any machine that I login.I don't want to manually set aliases everytime I login to a new machine.

I have all my aliases in .bashrc_aliases

Comment: Is there anything wrong with setting up your remote system properly, i.e. copying .bashrc and .bashrc_aliases (probably .bash_profile) from your local to your remote machine?

Comment: @ThomasKühn . There are hundereds of machines and they do not belong to me. Ideally I would want those aliases to be applied only for that session.

Comment: May be it's best if you as this question on superuser.

Comment: If you set "PermitLocalCommand" and "LocalCommand" in ~/.ssh/config, you can execute local commands on the remote host on connection. Problem is that a bash shell is spawned to execute the commands and so they won't be relevant to your ssh session. Accepted practice would be for these remote machines to have an account specifically set up for yourself allowing you to make changes to your bash profile as you please. I know you have no control over these servers but they should be following what many consider as "common practice"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, first split aliases from `.bashrc` into `.bashrc_aliases` and load it dynamically in `.bashrc` with:

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

From here, there are several options. I use a `dotfiles` repository, where I manage my `.bash_aliases` centrally. If I need it on a remote machine, here is a quick-setup-command:

First, set the remote repo URL and cd into the home directory:

```sh
cd ~
export DOTFILES=git@gitlab.local.domain.tld/user/dotfiles.git
```

Then use the following command to
clone, link and update aliases into the `.bashrc` file:

```sh
git clone $DOTFILES \
    && ln -s ~/dotfiles/.bash_aliases ~/.bash_aliases \
    && export ALIAS_LOAD="# load aliases\nif [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then\n    . ~/.bash_aliases\nfi\n\n" \
    && printf "$ALIAS_LOAD" | cat - .bashrc > tmpfile \
    && mv tmpfile .bashrc
```